# How to impose numerical sort with jQuery and dataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTables jQuery plugin. I am trying to enable sort interaction, but when sorting it sorts alphabetically and not numerically. As you can see in the enclosed picture, `-4317.93` is shown after `-631` and `-456`. How can I make `DataTable` sort a column numerically?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Updated answer**

With the latest version of DataTables you need to set the `type` property of the object you provide in the `columnDefs` array, like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    { "type": "num" }
  ]
});
```

Note that there are many other methods of sorting which can be found in the [documentation](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting)

---

**Original answer**

You need to add the `sType` parameter to your column definition.

For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "aoColumnDefs": [
    { "sType": "numeric" }
  ]
});
```

More information in the DataTable documentation: http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

Comment: Thank you. This worked but when I applied this sort functionality of this column has been stopped working. Can you please let me know how to add sort functionality to this numeric column. Thanks in advance