# jquery datatable serverside pagination stype null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, odata

I use jquery datatables with serverside processing. It works fine til press pagination battons. When user press pagination button fnServerData call with oSettings argument with no sType parametr!
for example call fnServerData after Next button:
[image]

The same call after some filter button:
[image]

Is it a datatables bug or  what? how can i fix it?

UPD: my datatables initialization

```
var table = $("#table_id").DataTable(
    {
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "sAjaxSource": "/odata/Messages",
        "iODataVersion": 4,
        "aoColumns": [
            { mData: "Id", sType: "numeric" },
            ...
        ],
        "fnServerData": fnServerOData, 
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bUseODataViaJSONP": false,            
        "processing": true,            
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 100, 1000], [10, 100, 1000]]            
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to impose numerical sort with jQuery and dataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008442/how-to-impose-numerical-sort-with-jquery-and-datatables)

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Rory McCrossan over [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008442/how-to-impose-numerical-sort-with-jquery-and-datatables),

With the latest version of `DataTables`, you need to set the type property of the object you provide in the `columnDefs` array, like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    { "type": "num" }
  ]
});
```

Note that there are many other methods of sorting which can be found in the [documentation](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)

For more info : [**stype-numeric-doesnt-seem-to-work-anymore**](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20807/stype-numeric-doesnt-seem-to-work-anymore) (Datatable official)

Comment: u mean not "numeric" but "num" ? couse i initialize datatable with { mData: "Id", sType: "numeric" } and it works fine on filtering!

Comment: @Timur Lemeshko, yes.